# Bind rows based on status

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table like:

```
logID   eventID repID   statusID    logTime
174356  228985  107959  1           2013-05-03 09:25:41.000
174391  228985  107959  1           2013-05-03 10:06:33.000
174588  228985  107959  2           2013-05-03 14:59:51.000
```

I want the Output as

```
Date    ClockIn         ClockOut
05/03/2013  9:25:41 AM  
05/03/2013  10:06:33 AM 2:59:51 PM
```

ie.. If the Status is 1 it has to be in ClockIn and if 2 in ClockOut.

But Iam getting the output as

```
Date    ClockIn         ClockOut
05/03/2013  9:25:41 AM  2:59:51 PM
05/03/2013  10:06:33 AM 2:59:51 PM
```

I have checked as if the status is 2 and if it is greater than clock in time, then it has to be displayed under clock out time...

My Query:

```
Select LTRIM(RIGHT(CONVERT(CHAR(20), rt.logTime, 22), 11)) as ClockIn, 
LTRIM(RIGHT(CONVERT(CHAR(20), Min(rt1.logTime), 22), 11)) as ClockOut
from table1 rt
join table1  rt1  ON rt.repID = rt1.repID and rt1.statusID=2 
AND CONVERT(nvarchar(25), rt.logTime,101) = CONVERT(nvarchar(25), rt1.logTime,101) AND rt.logTime<rt1.logTime
where rt.eventID='228985' and rt.repID='107959' and CONVERT(date, rt.logTime) = CONVERT(date, '05/03/2013')
group by rt.logTime, rt1.logTime
```

How should I get the desired result.........

Comment: please post your query

Comment: Please refer my updated Question for Query

Comment: Are you using mySql or SqlServer? Please edit your tags to select the relevant one!

Comment: Iam using sql Server...I have edited my tags....

Comment: There is no unique key between the statusID = 1 and statusID = 2 posts. Both repid and eventid is the same in all rows. Foreach row with statusid = 2 you'll need to match it with the row with statusid = 1 that is closest in time. For every row with statusid = 2 that is already taken by you'll need to output empty in clockout. This is not easily expressed in SQL...

Comment: Why did you use MIN (rt1.Logime) for ClockOut?. What if the rep have 2 logtime with status as 2?

Comment: without clockIn Clock out will not be there... So among the clockout time Iam choosing Min time related to clock in

Comment: well, as you can see in your data above, since there is one "clockin" missing a "clockout" both those "clockin"s will bind to the *same* "clockout" You'll need anohter approach

Answer (score 1):

Try this answer.

```
    SELECT LTRIM(RIGHT(CONVERT(CHAR(20), rt.logTime, 22), 11)) AS ClockIn,
    LTRIM(RIGHT(CONVERT(CHAR(20), Min(rt1.logTime), 22), 11)) AS ClockOut
FROM table1 rt
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT eventID,
        repID,
        CONVERT(DATE, logTime) LogTime,
        MAX(logId) LogID
    FROM table1
    WHERE StatusID = 1
    GROUP BY eventID,
        repID,
        CONVERT(DATE, logTime)
    ) rr
    ON rt.LogId = rr.logId
LEFT JOIN table1 rt1
    ON rr.repID = rt1.repID
        AND rt1.statusID = 2
        AND CONVERT(NVARCHAR(25), rr.logTime, 101) = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(25), rt1.logTime, 101)
        AND rt.logTime < rt1.logTime
WHERE rt.StatusID = 1
    AND rt.eventID = '228985'
    AND rt.repID = '107959'
    AND CONVERT(DATE, rt.logTime) = CONVERT(DATE, '05/03/2013')
GROUP BY rt.logTime,
    rt1.logTime
```

**[Fiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3ebeb/1/0)**

Comment: Hi...Thanks for the reply.. It works for some situation... It work for the above set of datas. But when that table contains all clockIn and ClockOut correctly, the first row is still returning the Clockout as Null...

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please try now. That was a careless issue.

Comment: It works... But when I insert a column like - insert into table1
values(174356 , 228985,  107959 , 2,           '2013-05-03 09:30:41.000').... Then it is not showing the clock out time.....

Comment: [Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1cdcad/1/0) I have added table structure for sample... It shows wrong output